# Will NAudio  support  Mac OSX

Tags: macos, naudio

Now I am trying to use NAudio to play .wav and .mp3 files in my application for Windows Operating system.

Will this NAudio support Mac OS X?

Comment: I managed to find a version that works for Mac OSX in the Unity asset store as part of another package. "Midi Tool Kit Free".

Comment: NAudio v2 opens up such possibility in the future.

Answer (score 3):

NAudio contains a lot of interop wrappers for Windows functions. You are likely to be using WaveOut (which uses the Windows waveOut APIs) and WaveFormatConversionStream (which uses the Windows ACM APIs) if you are playing MP3 files with NAudio, so the answer is no, this won't work on MacOS, even if you use Mono. You would be better off finding a cross-platform audio API.

Comment: Are there any cross-platform C# audio APIs?

Answer (score 0):

NAudio is targeted for the .NET framework, so I bet there won't be support for Mac platform.

Comment: Ok, then if I need to play the audio files in both operating systems, is there any easy way or any other solution.