# MonoDevelop + NAudio + Ubuntu Linux tells me Winmm.dll not found?

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, monodevelop, naudio

So I'm attempting to use MonoDevelop with NAudio and Ubuntu Linux, For some reason It errors saying that winmm.dll isn't found so I attempted to download it and and the "Add Reference" dialogue claims its not a valid .NET library. Here is my code....

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Gst;
using GLib;
using Gst.BasePlugins;

using NAudio;
using NAudio.Wave;


namespace record_audio_simple_test
{


class MainClass
{

        //Define class variables
        private NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader waveFile = null;
        private NAudio.Wave.DirectSoundOut output = null;

        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            WaveFileReader waveFile = new WaveFileReader("../../convo47.wav");
        }
    }
}
```

It says the errors on this line
**WaveFileReader waveFile = new WaveFileReader("../../convo47.wav");**

Comment: That means that NAudio doesn't work with Mono.

Comment: SLaks, Can you direct to me why you came up with conclusion or perhaps give me a reason why you think this or perhaps a past experience that could be used to explain why you think?

Comment: That sounds like a Windows native DLL that it's using through P/Invoke.  Unless you can get that DLL to work on Wine, you're probably out of luck.  Google it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6191434/34397

Comment: Unless there is an official announcement from http://naudio.codeplex.com/ that Mono/Linux is supported, you should by default assume it (as well as many other .NET libraries) is not compatible with Mono/Linux. That's a rule of thumb you should follow in the future.

Comment: Thank you for the informative information everyone. I learn every day

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A large part of NAudio consists of interop wrappers to access Windows API calls such as waveIn/waveOut, DirectSound, WASAPI, ACM, MediaFoundation and DMO. None of these are going to work on Linux since those API methods don't exist. I suppose it might be theoretically possible for them to work on top of a Windows API emulation layer, but really it would be better to create an implementation of `IWavePlayer` that calls into Linux sound APIs.

There are some parts of NAudio that ought to work cross-platform, such as most of the `IWaveProvider` and `ISampleProvider` implementations. `WaveFileReader` perhaps ought to work, but is failing since it makes use of the `mmioStringToFOURCC` Windows API call. I'll be removing this dependency shortly as it is currently stopping `WaveFileReader` from being used in Windows Store apps as well.

Comment: Is there any alternatives the same or almost the same like NAudio for Linux? Maybe you know?