# Can NAudio work on Ubuntu for audio processing?

Tags: c#, ubuntu, naudio

I want to work on audio processing. Can I use naudio library while working on Ubuntu.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MonoDevelop + NAudio + Ubuntu Linux tells me Winmm.dll not found?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13793514/monodevelop-naudio-ubuntu-linux-tells-me-winmm-dll-not-found)

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate question here:

[MonoDevelop + NAudio + Ubuntu Linux tells me Winmm.dll not found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13793514/monodevelop-naudio-ubuntu-linux-tells-me-winmm-dll-not-found)

And as answered there:

Nope.  While .NET has succesfully been ported to Linux, NAudio relies on API calls to DirectSound, WaveIn/WaveOut, and other dependencies that do NOT run on linux.